# Xamarin forms resize Image bytes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am looking for a way to correctly reduce image size with in byte.

Here is my code :

```
if (result != null)
{
    var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();


    byte[] bytes;
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
      
        // resize image bytes here (image can be square or rectagle) 
        // resize image if size up to 512KB
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say `reduce the image by weight`'.  Images don't have weight.  An image in memory is not compressed.  It requires width x height x pixel_size bytes.  Now, if you write it ti disk, you can write it as a PNG or a JPG, and then it will be compressed.

Comment: @TimRoberts Sorry yes I m looking for a way to correctly reduce an image in xamarin foms

Comment: there are MANY existing posts on this topic.  Please search before posting